# How to add a floating div that moves with scrollbar?

Tags: css

Business purpose: I'm building an admin page that is pretty long vertically, i.e., the user has to scroll down sometimes to see the content.  After the user edits something, I make a "Save" button enabled.

Question: how do I position a div so that it's absolutely at right: 5px, bottom: 5px;, and it stays in that position when you scroll up and down?  So, when I scroll down, it's still in the far right lower corner?

Hopefully that's descriptive enough!

Thanks!

Comment: why this would be nice: if the user scrolls down, edits something towards the bottom, he/she can just click the Save button that's always at the lower right corner of screen.  He/she doesn't have to scroll all the way back up to where the Save button is, if I just have it always at the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the CSS [position:fixed;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) property.

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport.  This is often used to create a floating element that stays in the same position even after scrolling the page.